# Codeigniter query not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have tried to fix the query but it still doesn't work

This is the error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO user_notifications (`id,` usr_id`,` notification_message`,` sender`,' at line 3
>
> DELETE FROM account_requests WHERE `usrs_id` = '' AND `account_requesting` = '2'; INSERT INTO user_notifications (`id,` usr_id`,` notification_message`,` sender`, show,` date`) VALUES (NULL, '', 'Successful account upgrade. You are now a Tutor', 'Codeg Account Wizard', 1, CURDATE()); INSERT INTO usrs_acc_type (`usrs_usr_id`,` account_type_type_id`) VALUES (, 2); UPDATE` transaction`SET`order_status`= 'Completed' WHERE`usr_id`= AND`purchase_type`= 'Account Upgrade' AND`order_status`= 'Pending' AND`item` = 'Tutor Account';
>
> Filename: C:\Users\Supremekhaoz\Downloads\Dropbox\htdocs\codeg\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

The query:

```
DELETE FROM account_requests WHERE `usrs_id` = '$usr_id' AND `account_requesting` = '$type_id'; 
            
INSERT INTO user_notifications (`id, `usr_id`, `notification_message`, `sender`, show, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$usr_id', 'Successful account upgrade. You are now a $type', 'Codeg Account Wizard', 1, CURDATE()); 

INSERT INTO usrs_acc_type (`usrs_usr_id`, `account_type_type_id`) VALUES ($usr_id, $type_id);

UPDATE `transaction` SET `order_status` = 'Completed' WHERE `usr_id` = $usr_id AND `purchase_type` = 'Account Upgrade' AND `order_status` = 'Pending' AND `item` = '$type Account';
```

Comment: look for **INSERT INTO user_notifications (`id,** id has 1 missing quote

Answer (score 2):

if you are using codeigniter why are you not trying active records

```
$data = array(
   'id' => NULL ,
   'usr_id' => $usr_id ,
   'notification_message' => 'Successful account upgrade. You are now a '.$type,
   'sender' => 'Codeg Account Wizard',
   'show' => 1,
   'date' => time()
);

$this->db->insert('user_notifications', $data);
```

and also check your `$usr_id` has a value , i think it has no value

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('usrs_id',$usr_id);
$this->db->where('account_requesting',$type_id);
$this->db->delete('account_requests ');
```

You can use this code for deleting